# Net core web api - Error with "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" package

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have problem with my web api project. I have one endpoint for the login, everything works fine until I had JwtBearerAuthentication in ConfigureService. When I had it I have the following error:

```
System.MissingFieldException: Field not found: 'Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Authorization'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56067167/missingfieldexception-field-not-found-microsoft-net-http-headers-headernames), I try to change the package version but I have always the same problem.

Here's my code:

**Startup.cs**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<AuthenticationService>(); 
           services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    var signingKey = Convert.FromBase64String(Configuration["Jwt:SigningSecret"]);
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(signingKey)
                    };
                });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

**Authentication.csproj**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
        <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.0.0-preview5-19216-09"/>
        <!--      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />-->
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Login Endpoint**

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginDTO loginDto)
        {
            var jwtToken = _authenticationService.Login(loginDto);

            if (jwtToken == null)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            return Ok(jwtToken);
        }
```

Comment: i use .net core sdk version "3.0.100-preview7-012821" and JwtBearer version `3.0.0-preview5-19216-09` it works . show your environment to help reproduce .

Comment: Hi @NanYu.

I use .net core sdk version "3.0.100-preview-009812".